How can I get the Hypnotoad Worker ID?
Is there a way to get Hypnotoad Worker ID inside of Mojo::Log->format(&logFormat) callback function.
I like to add custom "Http Request ID" after Log Level in standard login format.
I managed to change standard format but I like to have Worker ID also just like in standard format.
Any help will be appreciated.
my $log = Mojo::Log->new(path => $logPath, level => 'debug');
$log->format(\&logFormat);

sub logFormat {
    my ($time, $level, @lines) = @_;

    my $now = localtime_to_iso8601_datetime({second_precision => 5}, $time);
    $now =~ s/T/ /;
    # custom Http Request ID is sent as last line
    my $httpRequestId = pop(@lines);
    my $currentWorkerId = "????"; # how to get worker ID to imitate standard log
    # [2024-06-13 09:36:06.19863] [?????] [debug] [123456789]
   
    return "\n[$now] [$currentWorkerId] [$level] [$httpRequestId] @lines";}


Are you asking about the workers  PID ? It’s in $$ . See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar

Yes, exactly, for some reason I thought that is some other ID. Thank you. Question is closed.

Mojo::Log uses the $PID of the worker process in its standard format. So based on your example this would be:
my $currentWorkerId = $$;

see perlvar for perls predefined variables.
